# HTML Creating a drop down list from database linq MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

During my project I have encountered a problem
I have a table of products and a table of suppliers supplying the products therefore when creating a product i need to choose a specific supplier from the data base the code I have tried so far just chooses an id of supplier which may not exist

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupplierId)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierId)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category)
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use `@Html.DropDownListFor()`

Comment: You need to use a little bit of google as well - http://tinyurl.com/pxrc4fb. There are lot of resources out there which will teach you on how to populate dropdown from database in ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DropDownListFor helper

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category)
</div>
```

[MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I need to access another table. the Suppliers table. do you have another suggestion?

Comment: You need to get the data from another table into your View? Why haven't you added that data into your View model? can you post your controller code?

Comment: In my Product table I have a supplierID veriable that represents the supplier of the product. when I want to add a product I want a list of all the current suppliers, how can I implement it in the product view?

Comment: Please post the current code of your controller and your ViewModel

Comment: the view as added above. and where I create new supplierID I want to have a drop down list there so i can choose the needed supplier.

Comment: Since you are providing very limited information I can only work with what I have. You need to add the `supplierID` into your view model and link it up in your controller, if you want to see a list of suppliers then you should create a separate view and view model.